# MonoTouch and TableView data bound on callback

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have a table view occupying half of my MainView. My view loads and sends a message to the server retrieving users online. At the return of the request I want to populate the table view. I do so using this code:

```
    void HandleGetUsersOnlineComplete (object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs<WordyMessages.Users.UsersOnlineResponseMessage> e)
    {
        var source = new PlayerSource();
        source.SetData(e.Message.Users.ToList());

        Console.WriteLine ("GetUsersOnlineCompleted");

        this.InvokeOnMainThread ( () =>
                                 {
            PlayersTableView.Source = source;
            this.View.SetNeedsDisplay ();
        });
    }
```

The problem is that this code is called correctly, about 3 seconds after load. But nothing is display. However, if I navigate to another page and then back to the main page. The tableview is rendered correctly.

Break points in the UITableViewSource is only hit on navigating back, never when the data is bound using the code above.

I'm sure I'm just missing something small.

Thanks in advance

// AnkMannen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must call PlayersTableView.ReloadData() after set source